Question about runup area surface markings
Attached is a google earth image of a runup area. Are aircraft supposed to do their runup in the area between the dashed yellow lines? Or are they supposed to do their runup behind the second dashed line (the one with smaller spacing). I tried looking for an answer in the AIM and the PHAK but couldn't find anything.
This is the Salisbury - Ocean City airport, SBY.


I'm not completely sure because the aerial view isn't detailed enough, but from context I believe the second/smaller dashed line is the movement area boundary.
Observe similar lines all around the terminal/ramp area of the airport: Along Taxiway A in front of the main terminal. On Taxiways C and D short of Taxiway A. On the compass-rose pad short of Taxiway C. Et cetera.
The widely-spaced dashed yellow line is the edge of the taxiway itself. Aircraft doing a runup should pull completely clear of that line so they don't block other aircraft which may not need a runup. It is not necessary to continue all the way across the other dashed line.

From what I understand, the marking for a movement area boundary has a solid yellow line adjacent to a dashed yellow line. You can see other movement area boundary lines separating the apron/hanger area from the taxiways connected to it at this airport

Perhaps it's there as a "don't taxi past here" caution to provide margin for wingtip clearance with the fence just past the paved area in the grass.

https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150-5340-1M-Chg-1-Airport-Markings.pdf is a good resource, especially see section 5.4 and Figure A-15 @randomhead.
